# How do I find all executables and start them with a specific argument?

Tags: unix, find, arguments, exec, executable

I have a directory tree containing some binaries, all of them support the `-V` option to output the version information.

I tried:

```
find . -executable -type f -exec {} -V \;
```

but got the error message

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

**How do I find and start these executables with the argument `-V`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct - I forgot that the binaries were compiled for a different platform, thus the `Syntax error`.

Running the same find command on the correct platform gives the expected result.